# Importing csv data into postgres using shells script

Tags: postgresql, shell, csv, ubuntu, import

I'm tring to insert scv data from .csv file to posgres database table `employee` having following fields  `employee table having emp_id, emp_name, salery,doj,emp_mobile_no`.
I have `emp.csv` file which contains `emp_name, emp_mobile_no`.
Values are  `David | 8989898989` and so on.

When I'm executing the insert query using pg_admi`enter code here`n, it is storing the data into database `copy employee (emp_name, emp_mobile_no) FROM '/tmp/emp.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;`
Script file is

```
#!/bin/bash
FOLDER=/tmp
EMP_Initialise()
{
  SERVERIP=127.0.0.1
  EMPSQL_INSERT="copy employee (emp_name, emp_mobile_no) FROM 
    '/tmp/emp.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"
}
EMPSQL_INSERT_DataBase()
{
  echo $EMPSQL_INSERT >/tmp/emp_input.sql
    /usr/bin/psql -U employee employee -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -f 
    /tmp/emp_input.sql -A -t </dev/null 2>/dev/null
}    
EMP_Initialise;
EMPSQL_INSERT_DataBase;
```

I would like to insert into data base using shells script.

Comment: So, what was your question?

Comment: as i have written i would like to insert data from csv to table using script. this script i have tried but not inserting

Comment: Do you get an error or nothing at all happens?  Are you running the shell script on the same server as the database?  What's in emp_input.sql?  Why are you redirecting stderr to /dev/null?

Comment: no i'm not getting error emp_input.sql is created in /tmp file which contains `copy employee (emp_name, emp_mobile_no) FROM 
    '/tmp/emp.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;` query